# Start Redux/React Polling after Login

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-promise

I'm new to Redux, this is a best practice question.

I have a server that i'm logging my app into, on a successful Login i'm returned a tokenId and an expiry time for that token.

tokenId is attached to subsequent API requests to ensure my sessions is valid. Before the expiry time is exceeded i'm required to send a request which generate a new tokenId.

Where is the best place to poll token regeneration? I believe calling an Action from a Reducer is against best practices.

Comment: It sounds like you could just put it at the API level. If you use [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) you can use an interceptor to intercept 401 responses (or whatever response you get when the token is expired) and refresh the token then.